# What wizards and witches owned wands made of elder wood (besides the Elder Wand)?

Tags: harry-potter

Rowling herself says only very rare magic users choose (or are chosen by) a wand made of elder wood.

> Only a highly unusual person will find their perfect match in elder, and on the rare occasion when such a pairing occurs, I take it as certain that the witch or wizard in question is marked out for a special destiny.
>   *Wand Woods* by J.K. Rowling

**Besides the owners of the notorious Deathstick, who else had a wand made of elder wood?**

Given Rowling's claim that such a person is marked out for a special destiny, I'm curious whether any famous person owned one. (Including both recent and ancient wizards and witches.)

Comment: No one listed in canon.

Comment: @ibid What is your source for saying no one?

Comment: @LincolnMan - No specific characters who've appeared in any of Rowling's writings were said to have had wands of elder wood. (Not counting *the* Elder Wand.) Obviously some wizards did have them, as shown by the proverb Rob quotes and by the Pottermore writing, but JKR has never specified which ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There aren’t any specific wizards known to have an elder wand.

None of the wizards whose wand woods have ever been mentioned have been explicitly stated as having wands made from elder, unless they owned the Elder Wand. There are wizards whose wand woods are never stated, and it’s possible that one of them owned an elder wand. Intriguingly enough, the wood of Dumbledore’s original wand is unknown, so it’s theoretically possible, though certainly not confirmed, that it may have been elder.

## There are other wands made from elder, though they’re rare.

In “The Tales of Beedle the Bard”, Dumbledore states that elder isn’t a wood favored much by wandmakers, most likely because of one of its negative associations.

> “And sure enough, within this category of unproven sayings we find:
>
> *Wand of elder, never prosper.*
>
> Whether because of the fact that Death makes the fictional wand out of elder in Beedle’s story, or because power-hungry or violent wizards have persistently claimed that their own wands are made of elder, it is not a wood that is much favored among wandmakers.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

However, “not much favored” implies that there are indeed other wands made from elder, though they’re rare because they’re considered unlucky and carry negative connotations.

The Pottermore writing on wand woods also has an entry devoted to elder as a wand wood. It goes into greater detail on the behavior of wands made from elder in general, and refuted the superstition that wizards whose wands are made from elder will never prosper. Instead, Ollivander considered it a sign that the wizard has a special destiny.

> Elder
>
> The rarest wand wood of all, and reputed to be deeply unlucky, the elder wand is trickier to master than any other. It contains powerful magic, but scorns to remain with any owner who is not the superior of his or her company; it takes a remarkable wizard to keep the elder wand for any length of time. The old superstition, ‘wand of elder, never prosper,’ has its basis in this fear of the wand, but in fact, the superstition is baseless, and those foolish wandmakers who refuse to work with elder do so more because they doubt they will be able to sell their products than from fear of working with this wood. The truth is that only a highly unusual person will find their perfect match in elder, and on the rare occasion when such a pairing occurs, I take it as certain that the witch or wizard in question is marked out for a special destiny. An additional fact that I have unearthed during my long years of study is that the owners of elder wands almost always feel a powerful affinity with those chosen by rowan.